# how to change the values of several dummy variables in R?

Tags: r

I have 167 dummy variables amongst other variables in my dataframe. For creating a newdata for prediction, I wish to change the value of the first dummy variable to 1 and replace the values of all other variables with zero. My dummy variables are called district_code2, district_code3, district_code4 and so on. So I want to fix district_code2 to take the value 1 and all the others to take the value 0.

I created these dummy variables using factor and added them to my data by using model.matrix
as in

```
 dummies = data.frame(model.matrix(~district_code, data=data_wht_81_09))
 #to get rid of the intercept
 dummies1<-dummies[,-1]
```

I need to have the dummies in my data because after I run the regression I donot wish to take into account the coeffiecients on all the dummies in my prediction. I want to plot the fitted value with respect to one variable holding all others at their mean. For district dummies this implies adding a constant to all the fitted values. Hence I want to put the values of all other dummy variables to 0. May be there is a more efficient way to do this.Below I am showing  a sample of the object dummies.

```
 dput(head(dummies1,4))
 structure(list(district_code2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), district_code3 = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0), district_code4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), district_code5 = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0), district_code6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), district_code7 = c(0,0, 0, 0),
```

I am only displaying the first 6 variables. How can I do this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are use using dummy variables rather than factors?

Comment: `dummies1[,1] <- 1 ; dummies[,-1] <- 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is rarely any need to manipulate dummy variables yourself (R does that behind the scenes when you use factors), but, if it is absolutely needed, you can simply identify columns whose name start with `discrict_code`, and change their value: other columns will be left as is.

```
d <- data.frame( 
  district_code2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
  district_code3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
  district_code4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
  district_code5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
  district_code6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
  district_code7 = c(0,0, 0, 0), 
  x = 1:4
)
library(stringr)
d[,str_detect(names(d), "^district_code[0-9]+")] <- 0
d[,1] <- 1
d
```

Comment: I have edited my question so that you can see why I need to manipulate dummy variables and maybe come up with a more efficient solution. Thanks a lot